# Firebase ListView Search Function Implementation Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-search, android-filterable

What I am trying to do here is that I have displayed a listview using populateView and I would like to filter it using a `searchview` but I am not sure on how to do it. Any help or suggestions would be great since I am new to firebase and android. I have also attached the code I used to display the listview.

**MainMenu.java**

```
public void makeItem ()
{
    lv = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://vsem-inventory.firebaseio.com/ItemList");
    FirebaseListOptions<ItemObject> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<ItemObject>()
            .setLayout(R.layout.content_main_menu_list)
            .setQuery(db,ItemObject.class)
            .build();
    mAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ItemObject>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(@NonNull View v, @NonNull ItemObject model, int position) {
            final TextView tvAmount = v.findViewById(R.id.amount);
            final TextView tvName = v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            final TextView tvSerial = v.findViewById(R.id.serialNo);
            final TextView tvSupplier = v.findViewById(R.id.supplierName);
            final ImageView more = v.findViewById(R.id.more);
            ImageView statusimg =  v.findViewById(R.id.status);
            Drawable paidIcon = v.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.succes);
            Drawable lateIcon = v.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.late);
            tvName.setText(model.getProductName());
            tvSerial.setText(model.getSerialNo());
            tvAmount.setText(model.getQuantity());
            tvSupplier.setText(model.getModel());
           final  String Remarks = model.getRemarks();
            final String cat = model.getCategory();
             if(model.getQuantity().equals("0"))
                statusimg.setImageDrawable(lateIcon);
            else
                statusimg.setImageDrawable(paidIcon);
            more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String serialNo = tvSerial.getText().toString();
                    String itemName = tvName.getText().toString();
                    String quan = tvAmount.getText().toString();
                    String supplier = tvSupplier.getText().toString();
                    showMenu(itemName,more,serialNo,quan,supplier,cat,Remarks);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}
```

Comment: What filtering are you trying to apply?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I cannot see in your code anything related to this. Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This question was asked to ask for suggestions on how to filter it. In this link here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54436518/firebase-query-not-being-updated) this is one of the steps I have tried .

Comment: Please access this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54436518/firebase-query-not-being-updated @AlexMamo